# How to Trace a Azure ServiceBus Message from End to End

Tags: azure, microservices, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-framework-beans

I Have 2 components(2 separate Springboot Application). one will put message into Azure Service Bus Queue other component will read message from that Azure ServiceBus Queue. i want to trace a single message from End to End. i mean, i want to print Trace ID into our logs(slf4j). so that i can trace if there is any exception had occurred when processing.

i did google. i found something called ApplicationInsights, but it will not resolve my problem. i want everything needs to recoded in splunk logs.

i came to know Spring Sleuth is correct choice to generate Traceid. i want to keep same TraceID between 2 components.

since my app's are separate component , sleuth will create separate Trace ID for 2 component. is there any way same Trace id we can use between 2 separate component ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to send the tracing data with the message (i.e.: in headers) and create your span using it.

You can check if [Spring Cloud Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/) supports it or not, if not you need to do it manually (you can take a look how Sleuth instruments Kafka or RabbitMQ).

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Azure Application Insights. It will give you out of the box end to end telemetry. you can trace how much time message was in Service Bus Queue, when was it queued, etc.